# Upgraded mockito, now getting java.lang.ClassCastException on Mockito.spy

Tags: junit, mockito, classcastexception

I just upgraded to Mockito v 1.10.18 (using JUnit 4.12 and PowerMock 1.6.2).  This used to work …

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@PrepareForTest( Transport.class )
public class AccessCodeServiceIT 
{

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    …

    @Autowired
    private EmailService m_emailSvc;

    @Before
    public final void setup()
    {
        final EmailService emailSvcSpy = (EmailService) Mockito.spy(getTargetObject(m_emailSvc));
```

but now with the new version of Mockito, I get the following exception on the above line …

```
findAccessCodeByCode(org.mainco.subco.ecom.service.AccessCodeServiceIT)  Time elapsed: 1.588 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mainco.subco.email.service.EmailServiceImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at org.mainco.subco.ecom.service.AccessCodeServiceIT.setup(AccessCodeServiceIT.java:103)
```

Comment: What is `getTargetObject(EmailService)`?

Comment: PowerMock 1.6.2 has Mockito 1.10.19 as declared dependency. Can you try again with this Mockito release?